# Odd behaviour in computation of intersection in Poincare Disc

Tags: python, math, sage

I'm trying to compute the intersection of two geodesics in the Poincare disc. My code is a bit too long to paste here so let me just share the short-link to it. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=dxqdvm
Anyway, I'm getting the following error in the intersection computation in a part of the code. Error message is `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`.

So, i printed out the geodesics involved in this computation as follows;

```py
Geodesic in PD from 0.9173343623719807 + 0.3981176554884141*I to 0.39811765407683164 + 0.9173343629845988*I
Geodesic in PD from -0.4409894081700523 + 0.8975123073706717*I to 0.7311976448002898 + 0.6821656721343501*I
```

Now, I understood that this much larger float-point precision sits behind these printed out numbers but I tried to reproduce the error as follows (https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=pooerg);

```py
from sage.geometry.hyperbolic_space.hyperbolic_interface import HyperbolicPlane

PD = HyperbolicPlane().PD()

l1 = PD.get_geodesic(0.9173343623719807 + 0.3981176554884141 * I, 0.39811765407683164 + 0.9173343629845988 * I)
l2 = PD.get_geodesic(-0.4409894081700523 + 0.8975123073706717 * I, 0.7311976448002898 + 0.6821656721343501 * I)
l1.intersection(l2)
```

But this time I'm getting the `ValueError: geodesics don't intersect`...

Could someone tell me why I can't reproduce the error?

#### Edit

- 2024/02/22 7am JST: Fixed the typo in the coordinate of point.

Comment: If you're getting an "error in the intersection computation in a part of the code", then don't ask about your full code: hard code the values that are necessary for just before you enter the problematic part of your code, and then show _only that_ as your [mcve] in your post. While you're using this code "for some purpose", if the error is with a specific step, single that step out, and then ask about that step with only enough code to show it going wrong.

Comment: The points in your two cases are different.  `Geodesic in PD from -0.4409894081700523 + 0.8975123073706717*I to ...` and l2 = `PD.get_geodesic(0.4409894081700523 + 0.8975123073706717 * I, ...` Note the missing minus sign.

Comment: Your problem might be caused by one point being outside the disk. Calculating the length of 0.7311976448002898 + 0.6821656721343501*I gives 1.0000000000000002

Comment: Fixing the minus sign and the calculation works `l1 = PD.get_geodesic(0.9173343623719807 + 0.3981176554884141 * I, 0.39811765407683164 + 0.9173343629845988 * I)
l2 = PD.get_geodesic(-0.4409894081700523 + 0.8975123073706717 * I, 0.7311976448002898 + 0.6821656721343501 * I)
l1.intersection(l2)`  result: `[Point in PD 0.449049143990937 + 0.517334825777205*I]`

Comment: @Salixalba Oh, sorry for such a simple mistake,,, my eyes must've been tired. And thank you for pointing out the point being outside the disk. Hmmm, the geodesics I provided were the perpendicular bisectors of 4 points in the disk so the point you mentioned is also automatically computed by `perpendicular_bisector()` [URL](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/hyperbolic_geometry/sage/geometry/hyperbolic_space/hyperbolic_geodesic.html#:~:text=the%20Hyperboloid%20Model-,perpendicular_bisector,-()%23).... so I guesss I have to dig in this function...

Comment: @Salixalba Sorry, just a quick question: how did you obtain a number with such a high decimal precision in SageMath? I've tried `sage.rings.complex_mpfr.set_global_complex_round_mode(n=20)` and seems that I was able to compute with higher decimal precision but when it comes to printing to check numbers, it doesn't affect...

Comment: I didn't actually use sage maths for this, just standard double precision arithmetic. You can trick to show the least significant digits by subtracting 1. `x = 0.7311976448002898; y = 0.6821656721343501;
z = sqrt(x^2+y^2);
print(z-1)` gives 2.22044604925031e-16

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans perhaps, you can read the entire post of mine first then answer! if you can't reproduce my error, then pls tell me. Thanks.